achilles pain after bike fit
I had a bike fit a few weeks ago as I was uncomfortable on the bike.  Prior to the fit on this bike, I had pain in my right foot, would generally sit on my right leg some causing sores on longer rides, and would 'hop' around in the saddle constantly, front to back, side to side.
After the fit, my saddle was replaced as it was no longer stable,  lowered 1.5-in (unsure of fore/aft), my handlebars dropped .5 cm by adjusting the spacers, and 2 shims were put in my left shoe (as I had mentioned that my previous fit from about 5 years ago showed a dynamic leg length discrepancy).  My left foot is about 1/4-in shorter than my right, but I had properly positioned my cleats over the average between the 1st and 5th metatarsals.
As a result, the pain in my right foot went away entirely, but I then ended up with pain in my right Achilles.  At the time, I was riding about 100 mi per day and doing about 6000-ft - 10000-ft of elevation whereas most of my riding is about 40 mi per day with about 2000-ft of elevation.  I wasn't hopping around the saddle like I was before, but after having been in this position now for a few weeks, I am starting to hop once more.
The fitter said that my feet should generally be flat when pedaling and after the fit, they are.
With all of that said, my Achilles pain has vanished (mostly).  I think that is since I'm riding much less with much less elevation gain.  But, I did start to feel it come back when doing a longer continuous ride but still under 40 mi.  I commute back and forth to work and that ends up around 30 - 40 mi.  If I do that with little to no break, then my Achilles starts to hurt.
Aside from stretching, is my saddle too low?  Why does my left foot / Achilles not bother me?
EDIT #1:
I don't have pain moving up and down the leg.  The original foot pain that I've had for years has gone away, but appears to have come back and I now also believe I have 'turf' toe where both large toes hurt when walking as well as putting on my shoes.
No, the fitter did not use a power meter, that would have been great.  I don't believe I had much discomfort while out touring, but mentally, I was intentionally reducing my power output so that I could handle the mileage without running out of energy.  I am primarily getting my miles by commuting and that intensity is much higher than my touring pass though I have to back off because of the saddle discomfort.
This past weekend, I lifted or moved about 1500 lbs of wood and did not bike that day at all.  I noticed afterwards that I had more discomfort in the same area as when biking so I think perhaps it is more related to squatting and the fact that with my lower saddle height, I am doing more of a squatting motion.
As far as the position on the pedal, yes, my left foot is a bit shorter than my right.  When I came back from the bike tour, I removed the shims under my left foot and subsequently that is when I also started experiencing this pain.  That said, I had never used shims before, so I am of the mindset that I shouldn't need shims.  Perhaps I need shims at this lower saddle height.
I think I have always had some discomfort, but never to the point where my sit bones feel bruised and so sensitive to sit.  I think that was primarily driven by my body wanting to be more over the pedals as my legs are shorter, but my saddle was further back.
Alternatively, perhaps this is completely unrelated to biking and I have something else going on.

I do not think anyone can really answer something like this. Everyone's body is different. The bike fitter has at least seen you, we have not. Pains can have different origins. Sudden increase in mileage/elevation can be one of them. This is a task for a professional and it can be a difficult one even for them.

The orientation of the foot relative to the pedal spindle is highly individual. If you forced it to be flat, you could be putting some strain to your tendons.

I would suspect the fore-aft position of the foot on the pedal.  You may be asymmetric and need something different on the left vs the right.

Without seeing you, it is difficult to be precise. Even if you posted photos to Reddit, you would likely get a bunch of contradictory answers from people who aren't actually deeply informed, but they think their experience generalizes. Also, your static fit is different from your dynamic fit under load, and a good bike fitter would be assessing you when you're putting out some effort.
If you're correct that they lowered your saddle by a full 1.5", nearly 40mm, that's a huge change. If the fitter was correct, your saddle was massively too high. If this was true and your saddle is now in the correct position, then I'd definitely not expect pain. Fitters are human and can make mistakes, so you should go back and see if maybe the change was too big. Generally, I wouldn't expect pain after a good bike fit. It will take your muscles some time to acclimate to the new position, and ones you previously hadn't used may wind up sore, but I assume you can differentiate that from something like joint pain.
Speaking of this, we'd normally recommend an easy week to adapt. The way you describe your current activity level doesn't really sound like easing up. I would recommend actually easing up.
In the first paragraph, you seem to be saying that your pelvis was generally unstable in your original position. If your saddle was much too high, then I would expect pelvic stability to improve after the fit, so it is odd when you seem to be saying that you still have some pelvic instability.
I have some concern over the cleat shims. You say you had a functional leg length discrepancy. That means your legs aren't structurally different (i.e. bones longer), but rather that they are different in practice probably due so some sort of difference in physical/muscular function. It would be better if you were given some exercises to help address the functional issues, but perhaps your fitter didn't know any. I think the better bike fitters will tend to have some idea about this. Also, lowering the saddle should have reduced pelvic instability, so it seems to me that perhaps they should have held off on shims until that was resolved. I don't believe most cyclists need shims unless they have structural leg length differences. Steve Hogg, an experienced bike fitter, reported that as of about 2011, less than 1/3 of his clients needed shims in his assessment.

The Achilles pain was not there today after doing a total of 30 miles with minimal elevation gain.  Agreed about using different muscles and that will take time.  I was expecting the fitter to say, you might experience a little bit of discomfort as you will be activating different muscles.  Agree about the dynamic leg length discrepancy.  That was from my first bike fitting, I told my 2nd fitter about it and they just put shims in my left shoe without measuring.  The 2nd fitter also recommended I get a shorter stem and drop the bars 1 cm (to match the drop in saddle height).

Be aware that pains moving up and down the leg is an indication of sciatica.
Sciatica pain in the foot is felt on the outer edge and in the fourth and fifth toe.
What seems to be leg length discrepancy (as partly covered by user Weiwen Ng) can be caused by a permant rotation of the pelvis which also can lead to sciatica.
Pain in the achilles area can be caused by a sore Soleus muscle. Does this muscle feel hard? Then use a foamroller or likewise.
Did the bike fitter use watt pedals (independent power measurement of each leg)? Perhaps you are pushing harder on your right leg.
Did you suddenly increase distance, load or intensity per ride/day/week/month before the incident? Do not increase more than 5-10% per week to stay safe. Remember cool down and days with low intensity/low load.
Be careful when selecting shoes. Does the width of the forefoot match? (The area where you are pushing). The sole should bend in a pleasant way.

Not increasing more than 5-10% is plain impossible for many. My riding is never so consistent throughout the year. And sometimes a big event comes.

@VladimirFГероямслава OP has pain. In such case it is advisable to ease progression "to stay safe".

Sure, and in fact I have written something along that line in a comment under the question (" Pains can have different origins. Sudden increase in mileage/elevation can be one of them."). However, maintaining such accurate consistency in the mileage or effort so that the change is just 5-10% a week is in my opinion impossible.

@VladimirFГероямслава yes, a severe headwind could even make that much difference
